# Timestamp script for Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I want to create a timestamp script for Google sheets so that if:

(E11:E42) is edited then a timestamp will be collected in E10.
(F11:F42) is edited then a timestamp will be collected in F10.
(G11:G42) is edited then a timestamp will be collected in G10.
(H11:H42) is edited then a timestamp will be collected in H10.

I would also need to apply this stamp rule for 3 sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the following boiler plate and fillin all of the ?s and other fillins

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='**********Enter you sheet/tab name***********')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart>4 && e.range.columnStart<9  && e.range.rowStart>? && e.range.rowstart<? ) {
     var ts=Utilities.formatDate("You fillin all three parameters");
     //you didn't specify where to put the timestamp
  }
}
```

If you have additional questions then please share the latest version of your code and return for additional help.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='**********Enter you sheet/tab name***********' || sh.getName()=='**********Enter you sheet/tab name***********') {
    if(e.range.columnStart>4 && e.range.columnStart<9  && e.range.rowStart>? && e.range.rowstart<? ) {
      var ts=Utilities.formatDate("You fillin all three parameters");
      //you didn't specify where to put the timestamp
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Theres 4 different time stamps . The first time stamp would go into E10 when ever a cell in E11:E13 is changed.The second time stamp would go into F10 when ever a cell in F11:F13 is changed. The third time stamp would go into cell G10 when ever a cell in G11:G13 is edited and the fourth time stamp would go into H10 whenever cells H11:H13 are changed

Comment: There are three tabs/sheets : "Pagina 1" , "Pagina 2" , "Pagina 3"

Comment: Go ahead and make the required modifications and post your code in your question and I'll be available to help you finish it.